# Display specific records depending on user's choice

Tags: ms-access, report

I have a MS 2010 Access Report that needs to be populated by records that a user pre-chooses.  For example.

Form1 has 2 fields, LOT# (which is record id) and CheckoffBox (unbound).

User checks which Lot#'s (records) he wants displayed, then clicks REPORT button.  Report only shows selected records.

Can someone help me create the code?

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow the user to use a check box to select multiple records, the list presented in form 1 must be based on a table that has LOT# and a yes/no field.  (ie form 1 must be based on a query or a table that ahs this yes/no field).

If only one user will ever use this at any one time then you can simply add a yes/No field to the table that has all the LOT# values.

On your report you then only print those lot numbers that are checked.

Your report simply has to have SQL with a where clause that only print records that have the Yes/No field ticked. (=true  =-1).

If many users are going to use this form at the same time it gets more complicated as obviously they all need to have their own "set of yes/no fields".

So you  would need to copy the table with the LOT# into a temp table for use by each user (it might have a primary key of USERID, LOT#, or it might be a table with just LOT# and yes/no fields, that only a user can access - ie in their own copy of the database file that has the front end forms).

Anyway, assuming it's a single user, creating the above should be quite straight forwards.

On opening form 1, you might use the form_open event to run a SQL statement that sets all the Yes/No values to No. Although you might not want to do this.

Use 
    docmd.SetWarnings false
    Docmd.runsql "UPDATE theTable SET YesnoField = 0 WHERE YesnoField = -1;"
    docmd.SetWarnings true

Let me know if you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I want to have the Yes/No field unbound because each time the user prints the report, it will be different, and the lots he checked off today, shouldn't be on the report for the next run.

For example, today the user wants Lots 1, 3 and 9 to be listed in the report.  Tomorrow, it may be lots 2, 8 , 12.

The Runsql update would work, but I wouldn't want that to occur each time.  There's over 100 records and counting.

Comment: It needs to be bound there is no other way to sue checkboxes.  Simple run the update statement I provided to clear them when the form is opened if your concerned about performs add a WHERE clause that only updates row where the YesNofield = -1.

Comment: OK right... makes sense.  Thanks for your help.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Clearing the yes/no will not be a performance issue...   Do it on form_open as it will stop the form from loading data twice....

Comment: Can you help with the where portion.  Also, Access is throwing up a confirmation msg before it writes to all 100 records.

Comment: @user1899040 please tick my answer as an answer and up arrow it.  Thanks. Glad it helped.